# Finding File from a Folder

Tags: c#, file, directory

Currently I am using below code to find the next file from a folder. Basically I store the last modified date and time of a file I read and after i am done processing that file I need to go to the next file. But my code currently takes around 10 sec to search the next file using below code.

Can someone suggest a faster way?

```
DateTime lastfile = DateTime.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"lastFile.txt"));
string[] systemAFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("G:\\");

foreach (string files in systemAFiles)
{
    DateTime lastWriteTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(files);
    if (lastWriteTime > lastfile) //produced after last file was read
    {
        readxml(files);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For review and improvement of existing **working** code, you may want to check out [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  While your question is not explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow, it is more on topic on CodeReview.

Comment: Which part takes the longest?

Comment: I'd use `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles.Where(f=> lastWriteTime > System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(f))` which can be more efficient in this case, but i doubt that it makes a great difference. Are you sure that not `readxml` is the slow part?

Comment: No No.. readxml does nothing.. Instead of readxml even if i give a messagebox the message box will appear after 10 sec.. Because the folder I am searching in has around 2000 to 2500 files. :(

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to cache your results. You perform bulk of the work once and then quickly access the results from e.g. dictionary.

Collect times for all the files:

```
string[] systemAFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("G:\\");
Dictionary<DateTime, string> filesAndTimes = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();

foreach (string file in systemAFiles)
{
    var time = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
    filesAndTimes[time] = file;
}
```

And then, instead of searching all files again, you just access already collected values:

```
var myFile = filesAndTimes.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Key > lastfile);
```

Also, if you need to update times for the files you just add an entry to the dictionary. Note, that the `DateTime` is a key in the dictionary. If it were not the write time it could result in key clashes. But there are no two identical write times for two files so it should be safe to rely on `DateTime` here.

Comment: This looks interesting.. But how do i update the dictionary in runtime? I guess every 2 hours I will have to collect all file information.

Comment: @gauravmajithia that's where DRapp's answer may come into play.  You can have a class that watches and caches the files and the changes.  Then when you check it, you'll know you should have an up-to-date cache.

Comment: I agree with psubsee2003. The dictionary update doesn't come out of the box. You will have to add a mechanism to watch for that. What I wanted to say is rather that after making the initial search the dictionary updates will be quick and efficient.